# tomcat:deploy: "Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused"

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I tried to deploy my app to Tomcat using Maven and I've found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) sample.

That's fragment of my pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</url>
            <server>TomcatServer</server>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And when I run `tomcat:deploy` I get this error: `Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused`. That's full stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    ... 28 more
```

I didn't want to use authentication so I just skipped those steps. I thought that this may cause my error, but when I tried to add them, nothing changed. Do you know where's my mistake?

**UPD:** Sorry, but I can't check our solutions because I'm not working on this project anymore. But I will not close this question so if you think that your solution will work feel free to left it here and may be it will help to someone.

Comment: Is Tomcat running and bound to localhost? What does `netstat -an` tell you?

Comment: @Anders Seems like it is not running. I tried to launch Tomcat using startup.bat and then launch tomcat:deploy from IDE aaaand... `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I tried to debug and have found that it causes when maven try to copy some 128MB size array.

Comment: I had the stupid issue of not running the starutp.bat of Tomcat. Be sure to check that.

Comment: Try running `mvn tomcat:run` instead of `mvn tomcat:deploy`

Answer (score 30):

When using the tomcat 7 plugin, do the following:

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>tomcatserver</server>
        <path>/mycontext</path>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>tomcatserver</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
```

run

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

Comment: Just in case is useful to someone, the settings.xml must be on your .m2 folder. You may need to create it.

Comment: By doing it this way you don't need the pwd in your pom file. This is how the whole file looks:<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
        <server>
           <id>localhost</id>
           <username>script-tomcat</username>
           <password>tomcat</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>

Comment: this works like charm...have to provide username password at both places

Comment: Where do you put the settings.xml and tomcat-users.xml?

Comment: @botenvouwer, should be under the conf directory in the tomcat installation folder.

Comment: Downvote please fix. Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. In my case I fix it with run `run-war` instead of `deploy` for Tomcat7 with configuration:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080</url>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: thanks.. worked for me but run-war uses an embedded tomcat implying I lose my datasource configuration

Answer (score 11):

It took a while to understand the maven plugin deployment with **Tomcat 7** mechanism but it works as follows:

For use with the command:

**mvn tomcat7:deploy**

> > Tomcat server must be initialized first! You can choose start from IDE or at startup script located in the folder %TOMCAT_HOME%\bin

The output from running it should look like this:
[image]

**mvn tomcat7:run-war**

> > Tomcat not needed be initialized because the script above will automatically start the server. However, the context **/manager** will not be enabled for use in the browser.

The output from running it should look like this:
[image]

You can even run the command **mvn clean package** to perform a previous cleaning of the project.

Some additional configurations:

**[%TOMCAT_HOME%\conf] tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>

<user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat" username="tomcat"/>
<user password="admin" roles="manager-gui" username="admin"/>
<user password="pass@word1" roles="admin,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" username="mavenuser"/>
```

**[%MAVEN_HOME%\conf] settings.xml**

```
<server>
    <id>your_server</id>
    <username>mavenuser</username>
    <password>pass@word1</password>
</server>
```

**[%project%] pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>your_server</server>
        <path>/project_context</path>
        <username>mavenuser</username>
        <password>pass@word1</password>                 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: run-war uses an embedded tomcat, so it's a completely different setup (maybe that's fine for some cases though.) "Runs the current project as a packaged web application using an embedded Tomcat server."

Comment: to deploy Tomcat server must be initialized first!  tnx

Comment: you should start tomcat first then run your build mvn

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it appeared to be Tomcat version vs Maven plugin version.
I used tomcat 7 and tried to deploy with `tomcat:deploy-only` instead of `tomcat7:deploy` only.
If this is your case try `tomcat7:deploy-xxx`.

Answer (score 2):

I think one important point here, is that you should use tomcat**7**:deploy. Do not overlook the **7**.

I was using auto-completion and always ended with tomcat:deploy and just blindly ignored the little 7.

Comment: Not sure why you got tagged twice, but you are exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

So when I was using mvn tomcat7:deploy I was facing this issue though everything was rightly configured .

The issue was that before deploying I had to undeploy i.e mvn tomcat7:undeploy and then tomcat7:deploy.

Ooops ! that's such a crazy error.

Comment: this definitely worked for me with tomcat 10.1.5 and jdk 11 with tomcat running as a service.  thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:73)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 23 more
```

I check the log of tomcat( dir:`log/localhost_access.xxx`, then I found that when maven upload the `.wawr` file to tomcat, the http status code of response is `403` , which means access was fobidden.

Then I checked that the `manager` and `host` app has the same dir: `META-INF`. in this dir, I found the file `context.xml`, this file limit the access of `manager` and `host` app. the key text is below:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

Change the attribute `allow` to let your ip access `manager` and `host` app, then the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use XAMPP and i only managed when i edited My server setting
to edit the correct tomcat-user.xml...

Found it under menu in NetBeans IDE:

Tools > Servers > Apache Tomcat...

(Then under Connection tab, Catalina Home:)

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
```

Clearly it wasnt pointing to XAMPP application!! Changed it to:

```
C:\xampp\tomcat
```

Server in Eclipse (EE version!!):

Window > Show view > Other > Server > servers (open...)

(No servers available. Click this link ) << Click this on 'Servers' tab below
Then choose Apache > Tomcat v8.0 << confirm your version
Click Next
(Tomcat intallation directory:) << Search for the correct folder eg.

```
C:\xampp\tomcat
```

Then my tomcat user settings match those in tomcat-users.xml

```
C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml
```

My POM.xml in Netbeans:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  <!-- dont change -->
        <!-- below must match apache-maven-3.x.x\conf\settings.xml -->
        <server>TomcatServer</server>  
        <username>admin</username>  
        <password>admin</password>
        <path></path> <!--no path: deploys to C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\-->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Tomcat server entry: in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.8.5\conf\settings.xml

```
<server>  
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

Tomcat users: in C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>

    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx" />
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

I Run maven with goals (right cick project and Run maven)

```
install tomcat7:deploy
```

Before testing i ensure website is listed and running in

http://localhost:8080/manager/html/

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is because of Java Heap Space. Then you can change it using following steps, if it is installed as a service:

1- Run from cmd "Tomcat_DIR\tomcat6w.exe" //ES//ServiceName

2- It will open tomcat GUI. In JAVA menu, give memomry pool configuration.

That much memory will be reserved for Tomcat. It should solve your memory heap problem.